# What is the difference between reponseXML and loadXML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

My question is totally focussed on Microsoft (Trident) browsers. What is the difference between the reponseXML and loadXML ? Following two codes are shown:

way 1:

```
  var xmlObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
    xmlObj.async = false;
    xmlObj.load('/files/xml/books.xml');
```

way 2:

```
var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
request.open("GET", "files/xml/books.xml", false);
request.onreadystatechange = function() { var xmlObj = request.responseXML; };
request.send(null);
```

In the above snippets, the variable xmlObj in both cases are xml documents. But is there any difference between them ? Because I was trying to do something without ajax calls,
by using the previous snippet but it didn't work although the xmlObj had the xml file's content as expected. Kindly help. Thanks.

EDIT :

I found a difference. Let us consider books.xml is:

```
<books>
  <book>
      <a/><b/>
  </book>
  <book>
      <a/><b/>
  </book>
</books>
```

Now xmlObj.getElementsByTagName('a').length will return 2 for the second method (ajax call) and it will return 0 for the first method.

Comment: Why do you want to do something without Ajax calls?

Comment: I want to load a server side xml without ajax call. I need to use Msxml.DomDocument activeX object only.

Comment: @RanjanSarma what were you trying to do with with the XML document that didn't work?

Comment: Maybe MS is looking to phase out AJAX because it's open source...

Comment: I haven't looked at any API difference, but I'm pretty sure the first approach was the DOM Level 3 Load & Save which is no longer to be supported in browsers (I recall Opera had some support for it, at least before).

Comment: @RanjanSarma so you're saying they treat invalid XML differently? Can't you fix the XML instead (terminate `book` and `books`)?

Comment: @GCC - Sorry the book and books lement were not closed properly. I did the required changes. And it doesnot treat invalid XML indifferently. Both snippets will work only with valid xmls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference you may encounter between using those two APIs is the version of MSXML you're dealing with as you're specifying MSXML2 in one case but not in the other. In general you shouldn't see any noticeable effects unless you're doing a lot of XPath or XSLT.

As for those particular code snippets, however, they are quite different. Although you're specifying that the `send()` executes synchronously in **way 2** the `onreadystatechanged` event will fire several times so you should also check for a `request.readyState == 4` before grabbing the `responseXML`.

That said, because it's synchronous you don't need to use `onreadystatechanged` at all as `send()` will only return once the request completes so you could then just grab `request.responseXML` on the following line.

I should also mention, since you talked about invalid XML, that the error case in both methods is the same. Neither will throw an exception for invalid XML - you will get a non-zero `xmlObj.parseError.errorCode` value instead.

Comment: I made the snippets as small as possible so that all can understand
the code as soon as possible withuot much thinking.